# MVC CORE 2.0 Check path exists of Controller and view exist and if not, go to own 404 page

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to check if the path I'm on exist or not, e.g. does

www.mysite.com/foobar

or

www.mysite.com/foobar/delete

exist.

I've tried this method published 2 weeks ago and which seems fairly prevalent around the internet as a solution.

https://www.brainarama.com/thought/6e3d4320-ad5a-11e7-b750-89d12fa18e60/A-way-to-determine-if-an-ASP-NET-MVC-view-exists

But that fails with the code

```
ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, null);
```

having to be converted to

```
ViewEngineResult viewResult = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, null);
```

to get `ViewEngines` to be recognised even with `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;` at the top, but then `Engines` doesn't exist inside that, so I have the error message 
"The type or namespace name Engines does not exist in the namespace ViewEngines"

Any ideas how to check the path by other means or fix this code so it works?

Answer (score 0):

In mvc core you must inject ICompositeViewEngine service to your controller. the architecture of mvc core is DI-based.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;

namespace DoctorCode.BookStore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICompositeViewEngine _viewEngine;

        public HomeController(ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine)
        {
            _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewName = "Index";
            var isMain = true; //or flase for PartialView

            var viewResult = _viewEngine.GetView(executingFilePath: null, viewPath: viewName, isMainPage: isMain);
            var originalResult = viewResult;
            if (!viewResult.Success)
            {
                viewResult = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, isMainPage: isMain);
            }

            //do stuff ...

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```